# How to condense this code

Tags: java

Is this a good way to write this, or is there a less bloated form that I could use?

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Day {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("Todays date is : " + cal.getTime());


//increment by one from current date

        int OneIncrementalDay = 1;
        cal.getTime();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE,
               OneIncrementalDay);
        System.out.println("Tomorrows date is : " + cal.getTime());

//deduction by one from current date

       int OneDayDeducted = -1;
       cal.getTime();
       cal.add(Calendar.DATE,
               OneDayDeducted);
       System.out.println("Yesterdays date was : " + cal.getTime());
       cal.getTime();

//increment of 15 from current date 

       int FifteenDaysIncremental = 15;
       cal.getTime();
       cal.add(Calendar.DATE,
                FifteenDaysIncremental);
       System.out.println("15 days from the current"
               + " date is : " + cal.getTime());


    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using Java 8's Time API or Joda-Time, both will reduce the amount of code

Comment: This might also be better suited for [Code Review Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are using java 8 you can use the new [java.time API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html):

```
    import java.time.LocalDate;
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

     ...

    //or whatever format you want to use
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE;

    //java.time.LocalDate
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

     System.out.println("Todays date is : " + today.format(fmt));


    //increment by one from current date
     System.out.println("Tomorrows date is : " + today.plusDays(1).format(fmt));

     System.out.println("Yesterdays date was : " + today.minusDays(1).format(fmt));

      System.out.println("15 days from the current date is " + today.plusDays(15).format(fmt));
```

There are also methods to add/subtract months years etc

Answer (score 0):

What you have is good for readability purposes, but if you really want to shrink it, there is one thing you could do. Since each of the three blocks is basically the same except for values, put all your values in arrays of length three, then use a for loop to change the values appropriately, such as:

```
int[] increments = {1, -1, 15};
String[] text = {"Tomorrows date is : ",
                 "Yesterdays date was : ",
                 "15 days from the current date is : "};

for (int i = 0; i < increments.length; i++)
{
    cal.getTime();
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, increments[i]);
    System.out.println(text[i] + cal.getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If im the programmer for that one i will do it like this

```
  import java.util.Calendar;

    public class Day {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    public Calendar inCrementNumberofDays(Integer day){
            cal.getTime();
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE,
                   day);
            return cal;        
    }

    public Calendar decrementNumberofDays(Integer day){
            day = day * -1;
            cal.getTime();
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE,
                   day);
            return cal;        
    }
     public static void main(String[] args){

            System.out.println("Todays date is : " + cal.getTime());

    //increment by one from current date
            cal = inCrementNumberofDays(1);
            System.out.println("Tomorrows date is : " + cal.getTime());

    //deduction by one from current date
           cal = decrementNumberofDays(1);
           System.out.println("Yesterdays date was : " + cal.getTime());

    //increment of 15 from current date 
           cal = inCrementNumberofDays(15);
           System.out.println("15 days from the current"
                   + " date is : " + cal.getTime());
        }
    }
```